# GitHub - Commit message restrictions

Tags: github

Is there a way I can force developers to put `JIRA ID` in commit message in GitHub.

I have worked with Bitbucket and it was having a setting where I can sepecify regex  and it commit message doesn't match with regex, Push will be rejected. I am looking for similar thing for Github.

Answer (score 0):

You might still need to setup [a webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/), which will imply a setting up listener for said webook JSON payload.
But that would not reject your push (it might force a push to HEAD@~1 though, to cancel it)

[GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) ([examples](https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions), as [in here](https://thelinell.com/using-github-actions/)) could be another option (again with a force push to `HEAD@~1`)